# How to calculate accumulation interval of given power series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

this is a question I have to give answer due Monday. I already did most of my problems and for some reason this is the only question I am having problems with. I already tried to ask my collegue friends and teachers to help and couldn't get an answer. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n(x-2)^n}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a substitution $z=3(x-2)$, so you get a series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$$

This sum is known as a dilogarithm. Let us look to convergence: for values $z\in[0,1]$ the series is convergent, for $z>1$ divergent (use the D'Alembert criterium).

Let us now look to evaluation for values $z\in[0,1]$. For $z=0$ is the sum obviously $0$, for $z=1$ the sum gives the well known series with the result $\pi^2/6$. For other values there is no general formula except for some special cases (for example for $z=\frac{1}{2}$ we get $\frac{1}{12}\left[\pi^2-6(\text{ln}2)^2\right]$), for more information see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html.